# Soft Delete in Java Spring Boot MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I would like to do a soft delete with my rest endpoint in Java Spring boot with MongoDB.

My approach is to set the field Boolean from `false` to `deleted=true`, then save the entry to a different collection `"deletedEntry"`, which act as a bin, and delete the entry from origin Collection.

Which different approaches are available to soft delete without saving the entry to a different collection?

Comment: you can just update your entity with a flag, and always query for `deleted=false`? I don't see why you need to have this in a separate collection.

Comment: Depending on who's working with it, remembering to always query for "delete=false" could be a non-trivial source of errors. Abstracting that away isn't necessarily a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to add two date fields effectiveFrom and effectiveTo, then just expire the record when no longer needed.The only draw back is you have to filter your resultset base on the date, but its better that having another table :)